# Javascript args on parameters in runApplet method

Tags: java, javascript, applet, jnlp

I need to put arguments in a Applet but i must use the deployJava library js.

My code is:

```
var attributes = {id : "GenericDiv", code: namespace, width:200, height:200}; 
var parameters = {args: "{'eventHandler':'fingerprint'}", jnlp_href:'/xxx.jnlp' }; 
var version = '1.6' ; 
deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
```

But the code doesn't work, the javascript haven't attachs the fingerprint.

Thanks all ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Specifying an Applet's Input Parameters

> You can specify an applet's input parameters in the applet's Java
>   Network Launch Protocol (JNLP) file or in the  element of
>   the `<applet>` tag. It is usually better to specify the parameters in
>   the applet's JNLP file so that the parameters can be supplied
>   consistently even if the applet is deployed on multiple web pages. If
>   the applet's parameters will vary by web page, then you should specify
>   the parameters in the `<parameter>` element of the `<applet>` tag.
>
> The example on that page shows two different ways to define the applet
>   parameters:
>
> Consider an applet that takes three parameters. The `paramStr` and
>   `paramInt` parameters are specified in the applet's JNLP file,
>   `applettakesparams.jnlp`.
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">
>     <!-- ... -->
>     <applet-desc
>          name="Applet Takes Params"
>          main-class="AppletTakesParams"
>          width="800"
>          height="50">
>              <param name="paramStr"
>                  value="someString"/>
>              <param name="paramInt" value="22"/>
>      </applet-desc>
>      <!-- ... -->
> </jnlp>
> ```
>
> The `paramOutsideJNLPFile` parameter is specified in the `parameters`
>   variable passed to the Deployment Toolkit script's `runApplet`
>   function in AppletPage.html.
>
> ```
> <html>
>   <head>
>     <title>Applet Takes Params</title>
>     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;
>         charset=windows-1252">
>   </head>
>   <body>
>     <h1>Applet Takes Params</h1>
>
>     <script
>       src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
>     <script>
>         var attributes = { code:'AppletTakesParams.class',
>             archive:'applet_AppletWithParameters.jar',
>             width:800, height:50 };
>         var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'applettakesparams.jnlp',
>             paramOutsideJNLPFile: 'fooOutsideJNLP' };
>         deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.7');
>     </script>
>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

Source [Defining and Using Applet Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/param.html).